# how to make focused buttons/items (by TABbing/arrows) actually visible in xfce4 (Xubuntu) using Adwaita-dark theme?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce

Please, how to make focused buttons/items (by TABbing/arrows) actually visible in Xfce4 (4.12) using Adwaita-dark theme?
It cannot be distinguished :/ and TABbing (TAB key) is not usable :/

I am selecting this theme using menu -> Appearance -> Adwaita-dark.

This is how it looks like in Thunar:

[image]

when you press TAB several times you cannot reckognize which button is focused...

I've got fresh Xubuntu 18.04.1 install.

Comment: I've found theme files in here: `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita-dark/gtk-2.0` but there are too many CSS-like properties to go through :/

Comment: I've put the same question onto github, too: https://github.com/axxapy/Adwaita-dark-gtk2/issues/7

Comment: I'll repeat what I wrote in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1071693/248158):There's not much point in using Adwaita-dark for gtk2 applications. Use some other dark theme.

Comment: thank you, `blackbird` theme looks fine and hasn't got this issue

Answer (score 0):

Considering Adwaita-dark is GTK2 and full of awful hacks (as authors commented themselves in the template), it's best not to use this theme these days until fixed/updated by its developers.

Proposed solution:

**Install `blackbird` theme**, it looks almost the same and works flawlessly. Installation is easy, too:

```
sudo apt install blackbird-gtk-theme
```

For those who would really really need to use Adwaita-dark, I created an issue on its github: https://github.com/axxapy/Adwaita-dark-gtk2/issues/7

(decision based on reading and following @dk-bose 's comment)